# User hosts in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Here's a screenshot of the first three columns of the `users` table in the `mysql` DB available from phpMyAdmin in a XAMPP installation.

What's the purpose of the Host values?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have one username on multiple hosts, so you can decide whether to give this user extra-permissions or not.

For example you have user `emanuil` and you grant him all privileges on localhost, but if somebody connects from differen host with username `emanuil`, you wouldn't give him `drop table` privelege because of security reasons

'emanuil'@'127.0.0.1' - All privileges

'emanuil'@'%' - All priveleges except `drop table`

Comment: Why there are separate rows for `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`? Is there a difference between these two?

Comment: `localhost` is top-level domain name. 127.0.0.1 is IP.

Comment: Just to clraify: localhost can be resolved to any of 127.0.0.0/8 not particulary to 127.0.0.1

Comment: See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve

Comment: Isn't `localhost` a domain name that translates to `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: I wrote a clarification cause I expected this question :)

Comment: @Nemoden, Thanks for answering the question before I ask it ;)

Answer (score 3):

The `host` column states from which host the user is allowed to connect. See [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connection-access.html).